# Is playerglobal.swc the only dependency of the Flex SDK needed to build a swf file?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, fdt

I am trying out FDT and it has several bundled SDKs. Some of them are labeled pure and only contain the playerglobal.swc. Is this to compile ActionScript 3 only swfs?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you want to use classes from the flex framework, you'll need the flex framework swc/swcs, otherwise, yes, you are writing 'pure' as3 swfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Also keep in mind that AS3 Project Types will also have some Flex SDK SWCs referenced as well, e.g. the 'flex.swc' and 'core.swc'. This is because for certain types of metadata embedding, you'll need those extra Flex classes.

In these cases, don't worry about using the 'Flex Framework' and getting a very large SWF. These classes are very lightweight and IF you use them, they will be small.